# How can I detect the what the last scene was?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

So I have multiple scenes and what I want is that the transitions between the scenes are different depending on what the last scene was. So basically I need a way to tell what the last scene was? How could I do this? Maybe make a number that changes depending on what the last scene was that's accessible from all the scenes. How could I do this?

Comment: use tag and store it into user default....update that user default value on every scene

Comment: Bhavin's suggestion is probably the simplest. You could also create a custom init method and pass a value letting you know what the last scene was.

Comment: Right, that was what I was thinking of, thanks guys

Comment: or you could write into the userData property if you don't want to put stuff into plist

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem before and implemented it by creating a subclass of `SKView`. The cut down version is:

```
@objc protocol NavigationViewDelegate {
    optional func willMoveToScene(scene: SKScene, fromScene previousScene: SKScene?)
}

class NavigationView: SKView {
    weak var delegate: NavigationViewDelegate?

    weak var previousScene: SKScene?

    override func presentScene(scene: SKScene?) {
        super.presentScene(scene)

        if let scene = scene {
            delegate?.willMoveToScene?(scene, fromScene: previousScene)
            self.previousScene = scene
        }
    }
}
```

All you need to do now is set (in IB) `NavigationView` as your Custom Class of the view of your `UIViewController` and set the delegate.